# Unable to play http audio using avaudioplayer in swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4, avaudioplayer, xcode11

I am trying to play simple audio from http url using AVAudioPlayer however getting weird error . Here is the code

```
func playSound() {

do {
   let  url = URL(string: "http://<domain>/stream")
    var player = AVAudioPlayer() //tied to initialize it as AVAudioPlayer! too
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)

    player.prepareToPlay()
    player.play()

} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.description)
}}
```

Error:

```
AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6000030f4b00> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make player as global variable:

```
var player = AVAudioPlayer()
// ...
func playSound() { // ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however, I have tried that already. Did not help.